# Google API. Library imported has no attribute

Tags: python, attributes, member, google-api-client

I'm trying to use Google API and the build instance has no attributes. Not even the sample project from Google works:  https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

I have tried to reinstall the libraries and forcing reinstall using:
"`pip install --force-reinstall google-api-python-client`".

Code from another Google site which does not work either:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

API_KEY='my_apiKey'

GPLUS = build('plus', 'v1', developerKey=API_KEY)
TMPL = '''
    User: %s
    Date: %s
    Post: %s
'''
items = GPLUS.event()  # AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'event'
```

Answer (score 0):

The service you're building with the code you provided is the Google+ API Client. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/plus/v1/python/latest/) for this client there's no attribute or function called event(), and so you get the corresponding error message when running your code. Take a look at those docs to see what you should be able to do with this client. There appears to be a quick sample on [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/plus/plus.py).

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment. The problem is that there exist no attribute for any build. Even if i try Google+ or calandar it still gives no attributes.

Comment: For Calendar v3 it appears that there is an event*s*() attribute: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/. In your code you're calling event(). Is it possible you're just missing the trailing s?

Comment: Unfortionally no. Even if i use the code from google which i copy without any changes the "build" still does not have ANY attributes. Is it my firewall that does this?

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing i can verify that there exist attributes since the code is working but pylint in VS Code does not find the attributes and therefore mark them as non existing.

I have not idea though why this is happening.